# Can't find 'stock.quants' view

Tags: odoo

So i have promble locating stock quants in Odoo 11.
In odoo 10 you could find Stock quants when opening Stock Move menu, but in odoo 11 I can't find quants. any suggestions?

Comment: Under Inventory Valuation menu you can see list view of product, with Quantity on hand & Total Value. Open any of that product, and on Quantity on hand smart button you will be able to see stock quants related to that product.

Answer (score 2):

- In Odoo 11 you can find **stock.quant** view in Product form
  view.Click on On Hand button you got this view.
- Another way is you can on debug mode and on multi warehouse option and go to warehouse --> Location --> Select any location and open than click on current stock. This View also stock.quant view.